# Jenkins take a threadump of hung maven surefire tests

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, maven-surefire-plugin

Sometimes I have maven surefire tests that get hung, due to either races or deadlocks.

When this happens I have to discover what slave is being used, and then I have to log on that slave, sudo to jenkins account and execute either jstack or kill -3

I am looking for a simple solution like doing jstack / kill -3 when someone presses abort button on the jenkins.

Can someone suggest how can I automate this or some better way of handling this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been discussed in detail in [maven email group](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-users/201910.mbox/%3CCAF6DVKN5RyqaJh%2B8GQC9pt48JdsKy8PZVtjk0_kb4ndznbXo3g%40mail.gmail.com%3E). In the end I went with the below suggestion and added a timeout in all my test classes via `@Rule`

> Hi, you can create a simple Listener like this one:
>   https://github.com/apache/bookkeeper/blob/master/bookkeeper-common/src/test/java/org/apache/bookkeeper/common/testing/util/TimedOutTestsListener.java
>
> check on the pom.xml file about how to enable it:
>   https://github.com/apache/bookkeeper/blob/2f996dcf0159f945f7ec97ce7402e5d293009444/bookkeeper-server/pom.xml#L212
>
> hope that helps
>
> Enrico